# Joomla Breadcrumbs

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, upgrade, breadcrumbs

I have gone through the Joomla upgrade but after Joomla upgrade I noticed that some of my breadcrumbs path are not functioning correctly. The breadcrumbs path of the top menu are perfectly fine but breadcrumbs of the left side menus are not working correctly, they are just showing home (autohiremenu).

For example:
working path : http://dev.auto-hire-online.com/spain/car-hire
problem creating path : http://dev.auto-hire-online.com/spain/andalusia-car-hire

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to URL generation in Joomla there are some things you need to focus on.

1. make sure you have SEF URLs enabled in system parameters.
2. make sure you have a menu item associated with your landing pages correctly. The best way is to assign all landing pages to an article view or a component view. Using system links such as URL alias and so on will not always work as intended.